# Can 'Undesirable' and 'Overstay' status by SA hamper my immigration and citizenship application of Aus?

Tags: indian-citizens, overstaying, south-africa

I am in South Africa on a deputation for the last 5 months. I came on a 90 day visa and filed my extension well before the expiry. Unfortunately, I have not my (extended) visa granted yet. My mgmt. is suggesting that I travel back home to India with a letter/document from the local attorneys. The implications are that my passport would be tagged as 'Undesirable' and would be banned from entering the country again for 5 years.I have an Australian PR and I am in the plans to move there soon. Does this overstay impact my immigration to and the subsequent citizenship application of Aus? Appreciate your time and response. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't South Africa have a bridging visa of some kind for when you're waiting for them to process your application?